# How to make C++ function return to its first line?

Tags: c++, boost

So I have a function inside a win32 C++ console application like:

```
void initFFmpeg(string url ,string container, int w, int h, int fps)
{// we want to return here

    encoder.SetConstants(fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate);

    // ... more code...

    if (encoder.InitUrl(container, url, outputUserName) == -1)
    {
             // ...some more code...
             // Now we want to return
    } 
    // ... more code...
}
```

how to enable such returns?

Comment: Have you considered using a loop or recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that what you're trying to do is to keep trying various formats until ffmpeg successully opens the url. This is probably what you want to do (and IMHO cleaner than using a `goto`).

```
void initFFmpeg(string url ,string container, int w, int h, int fps)
{

    do {
        encoder.SetConstants(fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate);

        // ... more code...

        // use whatever condition indicates success
        if (encoder.InitUrl(container, url, outputUserName) != -1)
            break;

        // ...some more code...

    } while (true) ;

    // ... more code...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually there's an natural loop that you can express (`while`, `for` or `do...while`), otherwise it feels like poor design to want to arbitrarily jump to the top of a function.

The easiest way to do what you say you want is with a `goto`:

```
void function()
{
top:
    // ...
    goto top;
    // ...
}
```

**Edit: fixed totally bogus `do..while` example.**

Some people don't like the word `goto` and will insist on wrapping everything in a forever loop and using `continue`, but it's just a goto by another name.

```
void function()
{
    for (;;)
    {        
    // ...
        continue;
    // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically they are the same.  But the code is so much more expressive with a loop IMO.  I would smack any developer that used a `goto` in this case.  Nonetheless, I upvoted your post.

Comment: @John Dibling: Really? I prefer explicit `goto` over implicit `goto` myself but you'd have to fight pretty hard to get either accepted by me. Ninety-nine times out of a hundred there's some simplification or refactoring that can be done to express something as a real loop or split a function so that it doesn't have multiple responsibilities which is the usual suspect for questionable flow control.

Comment: @Charles:  I'm glad you un-deleted this answer

Comment: BTW I wouldn't do the for the way you've done it here.  I'd do it like this:

Comment: for( bool cont = true; cont; ) { // magic happens... if( !need_to_keep_going ) cont = false; }

Comment: @John But that ends up executing the rest of the loop body before the next iteration.

Comment: @John Dibling: I think I'd just use `break;' at the end. Having any more boolean state variables than is strictly necessary makes things harder to follow IMHO.

Comment: @Alexandre:  Not if you "continue"

Comment: "Some people don't like the word goto and will insist on wrapping everything in a forever loop and using continue, but it's just a goto by another name." This implies that other looping and branching constructs are not "just gotos by another name", when in fact they are. But they (including this example you single out) are much more expressive than just a goto. I see `for (;;)` and instantly realize that this loop is going to repeat until something changes. I see `goto` and I'm left to wonder "Where is this going, and why?"

Comment: @Charles:  I get what you're saying, but I disagree.  I can agree to disagree with you on this. :)

Comment: -1 for the `goto` suggestion. I see that people here are very polite about "agreeing to disagree". However, it's like agreeing to disagree about whether it's a good idea to let children play with high explosives: it's just an abomination, recognized as such 42 years ago. Look up Dijkstra's [Go to considered harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF). Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: I wasn't suggesting using `goto`, I was suggesting *not* using `goto` but explaining how to use it in case the asker couldn't/wouldn't avoid it. But if you think that my answer is wrong or unhelpful then you are perfectly entitled to your vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while loop or a for loop to iterate over the function multiple times. How many times should it be called? If just twice, you can probably just call the function twice, but for more than that you'll want to use a loop of some sort.

You could also use a goto, but a loop is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

It is very bad c++ style but maybe `goto` ?

Answer (score 2):

Given your code, ...

```
void initFFmpeg(string url ,string container, int w, int h, int fps)
{// we want to return here

    encoder.SetConstants(fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate);

    // ... more code...

    if (encoder.InitUrl(container, url, outputUserName) == -1)
    {
             // ...some more code...
             // Now we want to return
    } 
    // ... more code here...
}
```

... and assuming that you really do want to call `SetConstants` again when `InitUrl` fails, a natural way to express your desired "return" is to use the C++ `return` statement, like ...

```
bool initEncoder(
    string const& url,
    string const& container,
    string const& userName
    )
{
    encoder.SetConstants( fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate );

    // ... more code...

    if( encoder.InitUrl( container, url, userName ) == -1 )
    {
             // ...some more code...
             // Now we want to return, so:
             return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

void initFFmpeg( string const& url ,string const& container, int w, int h, int fps )
{
    while( !initEncoder( url, container, outputUserName ) )
    {}

    // ... more code here...
}
```

You can also do it with exceptions. That might be more clear but it'll probably be less efficient. Assuming that retries are common.

Or, you can use a `continue` in a `for(;;)` loop. I don't like `continue`, and it's not much used (at least as reported by Google Code Search a few years ago). But it might be just what the doctor ordered with respect to co-workers' beliefs about what's good code.

Note: it's technically also possible to use a `goto`, but apart from use in machine-generated code those are best avoided. For background on that, see Dijkstra's original 1968 article ["Go to considered harmful"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF). Although as of 2010 it's 42 years old, it's still a gem -- and best *not forgotten*.

Comment: This assumes that there isn't currently shared local data between "some more code" and "more code here". So long as it is possible, this would be my preferred refactoring approach.

Comment: @Charles: it depends on the data, there are umpteen+a gazillion different solutions to sharing data. E.g. parameters, object state, part of data structure, even having a trained monkey repeat a rythm... :-) detail your new problem and i or someone else will solve it or at least provide guidance. cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.  Use the do{ }while form because you obviously want everything to execute at least once.

```
void initFFmpeg(string url ,string container, int w, int h, int fps)
{
    bool success = false;
    do
    {
        encoder.SetConstants(fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate);

        // ... more code...

        success = (encoder.InitUrl(container, url, outputUserName) != -1);
        if(!success)
        {
            // ... more code ...
        }

        // ... more code ...

    } while(!success);
}
```

Comment: -1, you completely missed the `...some more code...` part. Stop downvoting other's answers. They're not idiots, they just managed to read the question in full.

Comment: Oh shite, so I did.  However, using a goto is not necessary and I will not be taking that point back

Comment: Ed, please calm down. There is a reason why others are suggesting loops/continue or gotos. Your edited code is incorrect, since `success` is only visible in its enclosing block (and you're missing a semicolon ;) ). You can fix it by moving the variable outside the loop, but then you taint the rest of the outer scope. You can enclose that with yet another compound statement, but then your code will be overindented. Using while/continue or even goto is not so bad here.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't mean that to come off as hostile.  I missed some semantics the first time around.

Comment: I actually tried to go back and remove a downvote but apparently there is a very short time span in which you can actually do that.

Comment: @Ed, not at all, I suggested that you calm down, because you were on a super-fast downvoting spree and then in the heat of everything you made a wrong edit. :) Anyway, I've removed my downvote as your answer is now technically correct. If you still want to remove yours, just make a trivial edit. (Poor @maerics chickened out too soon.)

Comment: Yay for edit powers.  Done, and thanks for pointing out the mistake earlier

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to looping or goto is recursion.

```
void initFFmpeg(string url ,string container, int w, int h, int fps)
{
  encoder.SetConstants(fps, videoWidth, videoHeight, audioSampleRate);

  // ... more code...

  if (encoder.InitUrl(container, url, outputUserName) == -1)
  {
    initFFmpeg(url, container, w, h, fps);
    return;
  } 
  // ... more code...
}
```

But recursion is less idiomatic in C++ than in some other languages. C++ compilers tend not to optimize tail calls and deep recursion can cause hard to debug stack overflows.

I may use recursion here if I knew for sure that it can't recurse more than a few times. Otherwise I would probably just use a **shiver** `goto`.